# How to hide a column in Ext.Net gridpanel only when the value of the cell is blank?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ext.net, gridpanel

I am using Ext.Net.
I have a gridpanel called GridPanelDetail, which has a column called Instruction.
If the data is blank, I want to hide the column. 
How can I do that ?
The following code in script "InstructionScript" hide the column all the time, but I only want to do it when the value in column 2 (column Instruction) is blank. How can I check if the value in column 2 (column Instruction) is blank ?
Thank you.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Email";
    var X = Html.X();
}

@section scripts
{
<script>
    var InstructionScript = function (grid) {
        grid.columns[2].setVisible(false); //--> How can I check if the 
                                          value of columns 2 is blank here ?
    }
</script>
}

@(X.Window()
        .ID("WindowDetail")
        .Title("Email Detail ")
        .Hidden(true)
        .Modal(true)
        .Listeners(events => events.Show.Handler = "InstructionScript(#
         {GridPanelDetail})")
        .Items(
            X.FormPanel().ID("FormDetail").Region(Region.North).Border(true).MarginSpec("5 5 5 5").Layout(LayoutType.Column).BodyPadding(5)
            .Items(
                X.FieldSet().ColumnWidth(.5).Layout(LayoutType.Anchor).Border(false)
                    .Defaults(d => { d.Add(new Parameter("LabelWidth", "115")); })
                    .Items(
                        X.TextField().FieldLabel("Email").DataIndex("Email").Editable(false).AnchorHorizontal("100%")
                    )  //Items
                , X.FieldSet().ColumnWidth(.5).Layout(LayoutType.Anchor).Border(false).Defaults(d =>
                    { d.Add(new Parameter("LabelWidth", "115"));})
                    .Items(
                            X.TextField().FieldLabel("Email Sent").DataIndex("EventDate").Editable(false).AnchorHorizontal("100%")
                    )  //Items
                )  //Items
                , X.GridPanel().ID("GridPanelDetail").Region(Region.Center).Resizable(true).Border(true).MarginSpec("0 5 5 5")
                        .Store(X.StoreFor<myproject.model.emailviewmodel>().ID("EmailStore")
                            .Parameters(p => p.Add(new StoreParameter("id", "App.Id.getValue()", ParameterMode.Raw)))
                            .Proxy(X.AjaxProxy()
                                .Url(Url.Action("ReadData"))
                                .Reader(X.JsonReader().RootProperty("data"))
                            )  //Proxy
                        .DataSource(Model)
                        .GroupField("Email")
                        )  //Store
.ColumnModel(
X.RowNumbererColumn().Width(25).Text("#").Sortable(false).Groupable(false).Hideable(false)
, X.Column().Text("Name").DataIndex("Name").Width(150).Groupable(false).Hideable(false)
, X.Column().ID("Instruction").Text("Instruction").DataIndex("Instruction").MinWidth(250).Flex(1).Groupable(false).Hideable(true)
)  //ColumnModel
        )  //Items
)  //X.Window
```